# AngularJS Routing not working on Amazon EC2

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, angular-routing

I have a web site designed in AngularJS (v.1.5.2) with some AWS Libraries for handling user authentication/api gateway interaction. The site uses an AngularJS route provider in order to handle page routing. When I run a server locally and test the site using that server, the routing works as expected.

When I try and run the site via an EC2 instance, the routing stops working as expected. Simple routing via  href clicks work, however routing by setting the location of the $window service results in an error similar to the following:

`The requested URL /permissions was not found on this server.`

My Route Provider:

```
/**
 * 
 */
angular.module('myapp.routes', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', routes]);

function routes($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/home.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'home'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/dashboard.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'dashboard'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/contact.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'contact'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/about.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'about'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/login.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'login',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/logout', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/logout.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'login',
        controller: 'LogoutController',
        controllerAs: 'logoutCtrl'
    })
    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/signup.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'login',
        controller: 'SignUpController',
        controllerAs: 'signupCtrl'
    })
    .when('/forgot-password', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/forgot-password.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'login',
        controller: 'ForgotPasswordController',
        controllerAs: 'passwordCtrl'
    })
    .when('/reg-confirmation', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/signup-conf.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'login',
        controller: 'SignUpConfController',
        controllerAs: 'confCtrl'
    })
    .when('/permissions', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/permissions.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'dashboard',
        controller: 'PermissionsCheckController',
        controllerAs: 'permissionCtrl'
    })
    .when('/error-auth', {
        templateUrl: 'html/section/error-auth.sec.html',
        activeTab: 'error'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })

//Removes Hash ('#') from route URLs
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

login.ctrl.js (`handleLogin()` is called to perform the routing)

```
/**
 * Login Controller
 */
angular.module('myapp.core').controller('LoginController', [
'$window', 'AuthService', loginController
]);

function loginController($window, AuthService){
var vm = this;
vm.username = "";
vm.password = "";
vm.rememberUser = false;

vm.handleLogin = function(){
    AuthService.login(vm.username, vm.password, function(success, result){
        if(success){
            $window.sessionStorage.username = result['username'];
            $window.sessionStorage.idToken = result['idToken'];
            $window.sessionStorage.accessToken = result['accessToken'];
            $window.sessionStorage.refreshToken = result['refreshToken'];

            // FIXME - Routing not working in prod
            $window.location = '/permissions';
        }
        else{
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

nav.tmpl.html (href click routing works)

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'home' }" >Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/dashboard" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'dashboard' }" >Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/contact" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'contact' }" >Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/about" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'about' }" >About</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right">
        <a href="/login" ng-if="!isLoggedIn" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'login' }" >Login</a>
        <a href="/logout" ng-if="isLoggedIn" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'login' }" >Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

nav.ctrl.js

```
/**
 * Controller for Nav Header
 */
angular.module('myapp.core').controller('NavController', [
'$scope', '$route', '$window', navController
]);

function navController($scope, $route, $window){
var vm = this;
$scope.isLoggedIn = false;

checkUserData();
updateActiveTab();

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', updateActiveTab);

function updateActiveTab(){
    if($route.current != null){
        $scope.activeTab = $route.current.activeTab;
    }
}  

function checkUserData(){
    var data = $window.sessionStorage.idToken;
    if(data != null){
        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
}
}
```

What should I be doing differently in order to avoid this error when I deploy the site to an EC2 instance? It must be something to do with how the routing is handled on the server side when $window.location is assigned, but that doesn't give me enough information to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my question, please state the reason so that I can improve the question, or else I'll assume there was no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.

All AngularJS routing is handled client side, however the server side can cause issues. Regardless of hosting (Amazon, Azure etc) its advisable to *set up some rewriting rules*, generally rewriting all requests back to the main page **(Index.html)** . I am familiar with the .net (IIS) URL rules, but not 100% clear with the Amazon rules.

This Amazon S3 article shows you how to redirect all requests to an Index Document [Amazon S3 Website Configuration Property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration.html). Hope it helps

Comment: This is certainly a new topic to me, so I'll need to do some investigation and work on this independently, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction! This looks like just the resource I needed.

Comment: Ok, so I've gotten the opportunity to review the documentation. The trouble is this document is for an S3 website. Mine is EC2 based. How can I configure similar rules for a website hosted on an EC2?